# How do I copy a value that have const unsigned char * type?

Tags: c, sqlite, char, constants

I want to store some value from SQLite database in my buffer, but the qlite3_column_text() has the following prototype:

```
const unsigned char *sqlite3_column_text(sqlite3_stmt*, int iCol);
```

then when I do:

```
out[size] = sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 0);
```

I get the following error message:

```
assignment discards qualifiers from pointer target type
```

I tried using `strcpy()` too, but I get same error message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's easy with [`strdup`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strdup.html);

```
out[size] = strdup((const char*)sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 0));
```

Note that this will malloc the copy, so you have to call free() on the pointer later not to get a leak.

Of course this assumes that your `out` array can store values of the type char*, you're not showing how it's defined.

Comment: It doesn't works for me. when I do `out[size] = strdup((const char *)sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 0));` I get `assignment from incompatible pointer type` `out` variable have `char**` type.

Comment: @Jack Did you `#include <string.h>`?

Comment: Joachim Isaksson: Yes. I did it.

Comment: @Jack Whoops, updated the code line, the cast to `const char*` got lost somewhere earlier.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Should work?
#define BUF_SIZE 512
char buffer[BUF_SIZE];

strncpy( buffer, (const char*)sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 0), BUF_SIZE);
buffer[BUF_size-1] = '\0';
```

Comment: But I want to copy all string returned from `sqlite3_column_text()` and I have no length of it. Then how do I set the `n` parameter of `strncpy()` function?

Comment: To know the length you can use the following call:int len = sqlite3_column_bytes(stmt, 0);

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to assign a `unsigned char*` to a non-pointer type.  You should do something like:

```
const unsigned char * out = sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 0);
printf(out);
```

A bigger question is what you want to do with this data and the lifetime of the pointer.  Note from [sqlite.org](http://www.sqlite.org/capi3ref.html#sqlite3_column_blob) "The pointers returned are valid until a type conversion occurs as described above, or until sqlite3_step() or sqlite3_reset() or sqlite3_finalize() is called."  So, as others have said, you may want to allocate memory and copy (`strdup` or `malloc` and `strcpy`).